# Отсортировать массив и вывести подчиненных под руководителями

Tags: php, сортировка

Не получается вывести информацию..Запарился уже..
Есть два массива:

```
// Массив людей
$arr = array(
  1 => array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'1Ярослава'),
  2 => array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'2Наталья'),
  3 => array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'3Ксения'),
  4 => array('id'=>4, 'name'=>'4Иван'),
  5 => array('id'=>5, 'name'=>'5Максим'),
  6 => array('id'=>6, 'name'=>'6Настя'),
);

// Массив сортировки и отношений
$sort = array(
  1 => array('id'=>1, 'weight'=>0, 'parent'=>0),
  2 => array('id'=>2, 'weight'=>2, 'parent'=>1),
  3 => array('id'=>3, 'weight'=>5, 'parent'=>0),
  4 => array('id'=>4, 'weight'=>6, 'parent'=>3),
  5 => array('id'=>5, 'weight'=>5, 'parent'=>4),
  6 => array('id'=>6, 'weight'=>4, 'parent'=>3),
);
```

Нужно отсортировать и вывести как-то вот так:

```
<div class="item">
  1Ярослава
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="item">
      2Наталья
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  3Ксения
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="item">
      6Настя
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      4Иван
      <div class="sub">
        <div class="item">
          5Максим
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

т.е. нужно отсортировать один массив по другому массиву, и вывести подчиненных под их руководителями. 'weight' - чем ниже число тем выше человек в списке.
Тут уровней 3, может быть больше.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: я как-то с битриксом сталкивался, там такой-же ад) думаю вам стоит создать новый массив и заполнить его в глубину, а потом уже рендерить.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, т.е. циклом как-то перебрать то что есть и указывать дочерние элементы?)